# Are microformats such as hProduct really being used or useful?

Tags: seo, microformats

I was looking at the microformat of hProduct at http://microformats.org/wiki/hproduct-examples

which lists websites that use it... But I went to GAP, Amazon, Target, Toys R Us, Macy's, Best Buy, and none of the product page actually uses this format.  Is the microformat hProduct useful -- is it mainly for Search Engine Optimization (SEO) and have most websites switch to using other methods?

Answer (score 3):

I can answer the SEO part with [this nice example](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3atupalo.com+kent+vienna&hl=all&pws=0). See the nice stars? That's the review micro-format at work.

Comment: That will be hReview though, one of the more popular ones. I think the question was specifically mentioning hProduct?